# The reason for the slow rate of receiving information from the sql server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel, xampp

We have a site written in PHP. We need to connect to the SQL server and read some information from this bank and place it in MySQL bank. But we have a problem. The speed of getting data from the SQL server is very slow. And we get 190 records in 6 minutes. We did this test local. And xampp is also active. We also removed port 1433 from the Windows firewall. We have followed the steps below for this link https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/

But our problem was not resolved. And it's still very slow Do I need to make some adjustments on xampp?

```
<?php
$serverName = ".";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "testDB", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8", "UID" => "", "PWD" => "");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";

    $array=[];
   $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM [nameDB].[dbo].[m10001_1]");
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $array[]=$row;
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
   var_dump($array);

}else{
      echo "error .";

}
?>
```

Thankful

Comment: It is a good rule of thumb to first assume that the database is slow. Try it from a command line first.

Comment: How many records in that table? Do you have indexes setup (correctly)?

Comment: You are issuing a `SELECT *` with no `WHERE` clause. How many columns and rows are in the table?

Comment: @ryantxr Thanks for the answer.
How should I do this?

Comment: @waterloomatt Thanks for the answer.
The number of columns is 22 but I also tried this test on a table with 3 columns and the speed was still low.
Indexing has also been done.
The number of records is 190.

Comment: @HardCode Thanks for the answer.
The number of columns is 22 but I also tried this test on a table with 3 columns and the speed was still low.
The where statement was used instead of * but no change in speed.
The number of records is 190.

Comment: A few tips here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/27553048/296555. Please try and report back.

Comment: @waterloomatt The speed of receiving the information is still terrible for 6 minutes to get 190 records.

Comment: Information is still vague. Can you post the DDL of the table definition? Do you maybe have a binary field with file data that you're selecting?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem.

The problem was with xampp. I used wamp and the problem was fixed.